# CSS format doesn't make article readable on mobile

Tags: html, css, wordpress

If you visit this [blog article](http://kisty.net/what-to-see-and-do-in-paoay-ilocos-philippines/) on your desktop, you'll see that the paragraphs are on the center. I was able to achieve that by putting a padding of 200px on each side (left and right). I did this because I felt the article is more readable, at least for desktop users.

But if you resize the window, you'll notice that the paragraphs are also moving, making them unreadable for mobile users.

**Is there a way for me to fix this?**

Note: All elements on the article are automatically wrapped in *p* because it's Wordpress.

Comment: It looks to me to be very readable on mobile. All the content sizes down. you can change the padding for mobile views using media queries in your css. As it stands your question is vague though. Are you asking people to write code for you. It is generally a rule here to post what you have tried.

Comment: I spoke to soon, the first article is fine, but then you definintely need to remove the padding from the css as @denisol points out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove inline styling from `<p>` and give it a class.
then remove `padding-right: 200px; padding-left:200px;` that you have given to `<p>` at screen.

```
@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
padding-right: 10px; padding-left:10px;
}
```

Comment: I feel so silly for not realizing that this is the solution. I followed your advice and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do some css hacking targeting mobile devices only. Try adding this to the bottom of your stylesheet:

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px) {

  div#main.fullpost p {
    padding-left: 0 !important;
    padding-right: 0 !important;
  }

}
```